# Pushing to data-bound array used in dom-repeat (Polymer)

Tags: javascript, data-binding, polymer, dom-repeat

I have a data-bound array (`dom-repeat`) in a custom Polymer element, and I need to push new data into the array.  It's not displaying the items, even though it knows 2 elements have been added. What am I missing here?

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f8tsj06t/)

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="main-element">
<template>
    <ul>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{people}}">
            <li>{{item.first}}</li>
        </template>
    </ul>
</template>

<script>
    (function() {
        'use strict';
        Polymer({
            is: 'main-element',
            properties: {
                people: {
                    type: Array,
                    value: function() {
                        return [];
                    }
                }
            },
            ready: function() {
                // Mock data retrieval
                this.people.push({"first": "Jane", "last": "Doe"});
                this.people.push({"first": "Bob", "last": "Smith"});
            }
        });
    })();
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Polymer's [array mutation methods](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/model-data#array-mutation) when pushing items into the array:

```
this.push('people', {"first": "Jane", "last": "Doe"});
this.push('people', {"first": "Bob", "last": "Smith"});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.7.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>

<body>
  <main-element></main-element>

  <dom-module id="main-element">
    <template>
      <ul>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{people}}">
          <li>{{item.first}}</li>
        </template>
      </ul>
    </template>

    <script>
      HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
        'use strict';
        Polymer({
          is: 'main-element',
          properties: {
            people: {
              type: Array,
              value: function() {
               return [];
              }
            }
          },
          ready: function() {
            // Mock data retrieval
            this.push('people', {"first": "Jane", "last": "Doe"});
            this.push('people', {"first": "Bob", "last": "Smith"});
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/VmKKbd?editors=1000)

Comment: Would you please look at this [other example](https://jsfiddle.net/nf7ncbsn/)?  Using "hidden$=" with a computed property doesn't seem to be firing even though I updated the example code with the Polymer array mutation methods.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: Not sure why the binding doesn't update. If you just want to hide when `people[]` is empty, you could do: `hidden$="[[!people.length]]"`  https://jsfiddle.net/nf7ncbsn/1/