# Polymer 2.5.0 - dom-repeat not updating

Tags: javascript, html, dom, polymer-2.x

I've been looking around SO for a solution to my problem, I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42979897/polymer-dom-repeat-not-displaying-the-dynamically-added-values) and [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40622982/pushing-to-data-bound-array-used-in-dom-repeat-polymer) but it doesn't solve my issue.

I want to add `<li>` to an `<ul>` dynamically but when I use the array mutation methods it doesn't work (I can log updates of the array properly).

I tried to use a JSON array instead of a simple string, and I tried to do a `this.notifyPath('peoples');`, but still, do not work

```js
static get properties() {
    return {
        peoples: {
            type: Array,
            value: []
        }
    }
}
_test2() {
    console.log(this.peoples);

}
_test() {
    this.push('peoples', 'test');
}
```

```html
<div class="flex__item--top list">
    <ul id="namelist">
        <template is="dom-repeat" items={{peoples}}>
            <li>{{item}}</li>
        </template>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: First, use a temporary array to push some element to an array. And then use `this.set('people', tempArray)`, this will make observable change on `people` array and will effect immediately at `dom-repeat`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can force `dom-repeat` re-render by calling the `render` method.

> **[render(): void](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/api/elements/Polymer.DomRepeat#method-render)**
>
> Forces the element to render its content. Normally rendering is
>   asynchronous to a provoking change. This is done for efficiency so
>   that multiple changes trigger only a single render. The render method
>   should be called if, for example, template rendering is required to
>   validate application state.

so if your `dom-repeat` is like this

```
<template id="list" is="dom-repeat" items={{peoples}}>
            <li>{{item}}</li>
</template>
```

You can force the render from your component like this

```
_test() {
    this.push('peoples', 'test');
    this.$.list.render();
}
```

Comment: I didn't know about that thanks,but still it doesn't work. That is really weird. I got the error : `Uncaught TypeError: this.$.namelist.render is not a function`. I dit : 
`_test() {
                this.push('peoples', { test: "test" });
                this.$.namelist.render();
            }`
with : 
`<template  id="namelist" is="dom-repeat" items={{peoples}}>`

Comment: Hey nevermind, When I came back from lunch I re-installed dependencies and it worked, even without the render function. Thanks for your time :)